# open a pop up on click of a link in uiwebview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have uiwebview which loads a url. When user clicks on any link I want to open a popup window. I know I can detect link click by using following delegate method:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

But the problem is that above delegate method is also being called when the viewcontroller is loaded. So the popup is generated on view load but it should open later when the link is clicked.
I hope my problem is clear.

Regards
Pankaj

Comment: If you are loading webView when view loads then you can use a `BOOL` var to prevent the popup to be appear first time. **Example:** in `if(secondTime){//do yor task here }else{secondTime = YES}`

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView   //WebUI
{
    NSLog(@"Web Page start loading.(Empty)");
}
```

This method called when a page start loading initially, So you can take advantage of it. This will call when user click a link, as it will try to load a page.